# couldnt save my jmeter testplan the following error is displaying

Tags: jmeter

```
2021-06-22 11:08:20,824 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel (in unnamed module @0x2b546384) cannot access class sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt.shell to unnamed module @0x2b546384
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel.updateColumnInfo(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:1158) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel.<init>(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:1145) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge.getDetailsTableModel(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:586) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$SortableListModel.<init>(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:1109) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePane.createList(DarkFilePane.java:129) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFileChooserUIBridge.createList(DarkFileChooserUIBridge.java:608) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFileChooserUIBridge$MetalFileChooserUIAccessor.createList(DarkFileChooserUIBridge.java:780) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge.setViewType(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:384) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge.propertyChange(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:918) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:342) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:334) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:267) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8713) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:688) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI(JFileChooser.java:1838) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(JFileChooser.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:308) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger.<clinit>(FileDialoger.java:42) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.computeFileName(Save.java:202) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:164) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
```

Comment: Please more details to the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's described in [JMeter Bug 65300](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300), the options are in:

1. Downgrade to [Java 8](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3)
2. Upgrade to a [nightly build of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)
3. Change [line 112 of jmeter.bat script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) to look like

   ```
   set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
   ```

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so if you're not going for the Nightly Build consider upgrading to the latest stable version of JMeter available at [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (it's [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) as of now)

Comment: On macOS, I was able to get this working by adding `--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED`  to the end of line 100 in jmeter.sh.